# Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

Tags: solidity, web3js, json-rpc

I'm trying to get some info from an array  using web3, when I try this

```
    async componentDidMount() {
      const product = await store.methods.storeProducts(0).call();
      console.log(product);
      }
```

everything works fine, it finds the data and everything, but when I try with getInitialProps(), it returns the error " Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "" ";

```
  ListProduct.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const product = await store.methods.storeProducts(0).call();
  return {product}
   }
```

This is the import statements:

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';
  import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
  import store from "../ethereum/OnlineStore"
```

This is what my package.json looks like:

```
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^1.4.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
    "mocha": "^8.4.0",
    "next": "^10.2.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "solc": "^0.8.5",
    "truffle": "^5.3.9",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.17",
    "web3": "^1.3.6"
```

Comment: What's `getInitialProps` and how is it related to the contract?

Comment: @Ismael what Im trying to do, is get the data from the storeProducts array, and then access it as a prop, in order to do that i need to use getInitialProps, but I cant seem to make it work

Comment: How are you using getInitialProps? Is `store` already initialized?

Comment: @Ismael I added my getInitalProps and imports to the question, any idea what can be the  problem?

Comment: I don't know much about next but since it work in componentdidmount your contract and abi are fine, the problem can be that web3 hasn't been initialized yet when getinitialprops is called, or it hasn't finished the initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some days I got back to it, and managed to solve it.

The problem was that the contract I had deployed did not have any data in it.

So, the storeproducts had a length of zero  (nothing on it), so I belive that is the reason why it did not work

Second thing that might have done is I got a newer version of Nextjs and Web3

Also recreated the whole project so that might have helped too.

I hope this helps anyone in the future!